# Given $\left(\frac{2}{3x}\right)^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}=\left(9x\right)^{\log _{10}\left(3\right)}$, determine x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\left(\frac{2}{3x}\right)^{\log _{10}\left(2\right)}=\left(9x\right)^{\log _{10}\left(3\right)}$

How would you approach this question? I actually solved this question, but I got fractions and really messy logs. I am curious whether there are other methods to avoid fractions.

After taking logs of both sides and applying log laws, I got:

$\frac{\left(\left(\log _{10}\left(2\right)\right)^2-2\left(\log _{10}\left(3\right)\right)^2-\log _{10}\left(2\right)\log _{10}\left(3\right)\right)}{\log _{10}\left(3\right)+\log _{10}\left(2\right)}$ = $\log _{10}x$

As you can see its very messy and prone to mistakes, so what can i do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Putting $X=\log_{10}2, Y=\log_{10}3$, the left-hand side is
$$\frac{X^2-XY-2Y^2}{X+Y}=\frac{(X+Y)(X-2Y)}{X+Y}=X-2Y=\log_{10}\frac29$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\log_{10}2 =p$ and $\log_{10} 3=q$
The from your work we get
$$\log_{10} x=\frac{p^2-pq-2q^2}{p+q}=\frac{(p-2q)(p+q)}{p+q}=p-2q=\log_{10} 2-2\log_{10} 3=\log_{10} 2-\log_{10} 3$$ $$ \implies \log_{10} x=\log_{10} (2/3^2) \implies x=2/9$$

Comment: Nice solution ( two typos).

Comment: @NarasimhamThanks typos made up now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take logarithm base $10,$

$$\log2(\log2-\log3-\log x)=\log3(2\log3+\log x)$$

$$\implies\log x(\log3+\log2)=(\log 2)^2-\log 2\log3-2(\log3)^2=(\log2+\log3)(\log2-2\log3)$$

$$\implies\log x=\log2-2\log3=\log\dfrac2{3^2}$$